# run servlet application in root of server

Tags: java, servlets, filter, websphere

I need to run a web application in the root of my server which will consist of a servlet and a filter. The application will act as a gateway to several test applications which are installed on my WebSphere server. My filter, should filter out any requests that are made to the server regardless of the context root, then perform some logic to determine whether the request is valid, if so forward request to the appropriate application.

If, for example, a request is made to http://project1.com, http://project2.com or any other app installed in the root of my server, the 'gateway' should filter the request, perform the logic and forward accordingly.

How can I run this servlet/filter on the root of my server?

Comment: Is your WebSphere configured to listen on the root URLs requests? Usually it is done by Webserver/LoadBalancer like Nginx that will be configured to forward to your gateway running on any context root.

Answer (score 1):

As tsolakp noted, it's usually done in front of the appserver.  But you could get close by using ear files and setting the context root in application.xml of app1 to "/".  Then any URL not explicitly mapped to another app would get picked up by app1,  it could look at the request url and then either send a 302 (browser case) or make a new request (non-browser case) to wherever things needed to go.

The limitation here is when you add app2 at context root /someotherapp,  it would be accessible directly at that url without going through app1.

Comment: Thank you. I did figure this out by trial and error. It is as you say. Is there a way to filter all requests to the server regardless of context root?

Comment: I'm not aware of one that can be done in a single jvm.

Comment: No, you can't (at least from the application server).  The context root is the first entity which the app server uses to find the correct application on the server.  Once the correct app is located, matched filters will invoke.
The front web server may be able to filter/redirect the requests.